# filter/subset a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame

Tags: r, filter, shapefile, rgeo-shapefile

I have an object, `O`, of type SpatialPolygonsDataFrame.Is it, there is a variable/column called `Notes`.
The column `Notes` includes string files where some of them have the word `double` in it.

I want to filter just the data that has the word `double` in their `Notes`.
If it were a data table we could do

```
O %>% filter(double %in% Notes)
```

But this does not work, neither the followings work:

```
O["double" %in% O$Notes, ]
O["double" %in% Notes, ]
subset(O, "double" %in% O$Notes)
subset(O, "double" %in% Notes)
```

Any suggestion is appreciated.

P.S. I am familiar with the idea of providing reproducible examples. But I do not know/want to go through trouble of making one. So, please ....

Comment: You may need `O[O$double %in% O$Notes,]`

Comment: Maybe you could go with `O[grepl('double', O$Notes), ]`.

Comment: double is not a column/variable/slot in the `o`. double is just a word that exist in some of the rows in the column `Notes`. yours did not work Akrun

Comment: Roman Luštrik you can turn it into an answer so I can accept it. Thanks a lot